# Can't show fractional part as .0 when value is a whole number

Tags: json, delphi

Here's the case:

```
uses
  System.JSON;
     
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  dd:Double;
  aJsonObj:TJSONObject;
begin
  dd := 100.0;
  aJsonObj := TJSONObject.Create(TJSONPair.Create('DecimalValue',TJSONNumber.Create(dd)));
  ShowMessage(aJsonObj.ToString);
end;
```

which shows

```js
{"DecimalValue":100}
```

What I need is

```js
{"DecimalValue":100.0}
```

I've tried to change `JsonFormatSettings` but I couldn't find a way to add the fractional part.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to format numbers with trailing zero? In case you consume the JSON value in JavaScript then it doesn't matter, because any [Javascript numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) are represented as double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of [`TJSONNumber` constructors](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONNumber.Create) accepts a raw string value that will be used in resulting JSON string without further processing. It allows you to pre-format the value yourself:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  dd: Double;
  aJsonObj: TJSONObject;
begin
  dd := 100.0;
  aJsonObj := TJSONObject.Create(
    TJSONPair.Create('DecimalValue', TJSONNumber.Create(FormatFloat('0.0###', dd, GetJSONFormat))));
  try
    ShowMessage(aJsonObj.ToString);
  finally
    aJsonObj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Using the above snippet the value shows as:

```js
{"DecimalValue":100.0}
```

You can even create `'whatever'` as number:

```
aJsonObj := TJSONObject.Create(TJSONPair.Create('DecimalValue', TJSONNumber.Create('whatever')));
```

to get this (invalid) JSON:

```js
{"DecimalValue":whatever}
```

Side note: you are responsible for releasing root JSON objects you create as they have no parent object to manage their lifetime. Use `try..finally` to `Free` the root object when you're done with it as you can see in the first code snippet. Too bad that [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/JSON) itself tempts you not to cleanup.