# How can I find out if a TJSONNumber is double or Integer?

Tags: json, delphi, numbers

I am writing a general calls to store and retrieve data via JSON. So when loading the data from JSON I can verify that it is a `TJSONNumber` but lack a proper way to find out if it is `integer` or `double`. Currently I do it this way, but I guess there are better ways?

```
FDataStore: TDictionary<string, Variant>;


for index := 0 to Value.Count - 1 do begin
   Pair := Value.Pairs[Index];
   if Pair.JsonValue is TJSONNumber then
        try
          FDataStore.AddOrSetValue(Pair.JsonString.Value, (Pair.JsonValue as TJSONNumber).AsInt);
        except
          FDataStore.AddOrSetValue(Pair.JsonString.Value, (Pair.JsonValue as TJSONNumber).AsDouble);
        end;
end;
```

Comment: That's the very point: [JSON only defines _number_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types), neither `Integer` nor `Double`.  Likewise you can assign both to JSON. If you must, interpret it `.AsText` and then look if anything other than letters `'0'` to `'9'` are in it - then you know. "Problem" solved.

Comment: Note that [TJSONNumber](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONNumber) is descendant of [TJSONString](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONString) which makes [Barbara Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) cry. `TJSONNumber` stores its value in inherited field `FValue` of type `string` (invariant format settings are applied when created from a decimal value). Did you know that you could create `TJSONNumber` instance from [an arbitrary raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64139798).

Comment: @AmigoJack don't forget to allow for `'+'` and `'-'`, not just `'0'..'9'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, `TJSONNumber` doesn't tell you the actual type, so you have to parse the original text to figure it out yourself.

For instance, by using `TryStrToInt64()` (rather than `try..except`), eg:

```
var
  IntValue: Int64;
  V: Variant;

if TryStrToInt64(TJSONNumber(Pair.JsonValue).Value, IntValue) then
begin
  if IntValue >= Min(Integer) and IntValue <= Max(Integer) then
    V := Integer(IntValue)
  else
    V := IntValue;
end else
  V := TJSONNumber(Pair.JsonValue).AsDouble);

FDataStore.AddOrSetValue(Pair.JsonString.Value, Value);
```

Alternatively, you could scan the JSON string for `'.'` and `'E'` characters (the only non-digit characters allowed in a JSON number besides `'+'` and `'-'`), eg:

```
var
  V: Variant;

if LastDelimiter('.Ee', TJSONNumber(Pair.JsonValue).Value) = 0 then
begin
  var IntValue := TJSONNumber(Pair.JsonValue).AsInt64;
  if IntValue >= Min(Integer) and IntValue <= Max(Integer) then
    V := Integer(IntValue)
  else
    V := IntValue
end
else
  V := TJSONNumber(Pair.JsonValue).AsDouble;

FDataStore.AddOrSetValue(Pair.JsonString.Value, V);
```

Note that `TJSONNumber` is also convertible to `UInt` and `UInt64`, so you may want to consider handling those types, as well.